# Servlet Deployment via JAR file on Wildfly - Page Not Found

Tags: java, maven, servlets, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy my servlet on Wildfly but I don't know what is the problem with the deployment process that I can't see my project on localhost. Maven build was successful, I can see the Wildfly main page and the JAR file is created.

I don't know what the problem could be because when I go to the Wildfly Admin Console I see that my JAR file is there and the status is fine but I can't see the JSP page that I should be seeing

Can someone help me with mentioning what the problem can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If deploying a webapp you should be deploying a `.war` file, not a `.jar`.

On your pom.xml change `<packaging>` element to `war`:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```